# Android nextFocus... doesn't work

Tags: android, focus, accessibility

I am trying to change the accessibility focus order when navigating through TalkBack

I have a simple relative layout containing three Text views, I am trying to change the focus order so when swiping right from the first text view (id=text1) text3 get the focus instead of text2

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dareyougo.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/text3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text3" 
        android:layout_below="@id/text2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Accessibility focus is different from keyboard focus. The `nextFocus` attribute only controls keyboard focus.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
if so, is there a way to override accessibility focus order?